# How to extend the Visual Studio Debugger with an IronPython shell?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

First the problem I am trying to solve: I'm debugging a C# application that has huge object graphs (think Building Information Models, a kind of object oriented CAD). When I hit a breakpoint, I generally have long lists of objects I'd first need to transform to be useful for debugging.

In code, I use LINQ and lambdas to do this. But you can't do that in the Watch window and the Immediate window.

How could I go about adding an IronPython shell extension to Visual Studio 2010 that lets me snoop the same information available to the Immediate window / Watch window?

**EDIT:** I can figure out how to make a debugger visualizer. But from the API it seems I would only have access to the object being visualized - while I'd actually prefer to have access to all local variables.

**EDIT:** From [the documentation on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/cc677253.aspx) it seems a DE (Debug Engine) with an EE (Expression Evaluator?) can do the trick. This is for integrating your own language into Visual Studio. I'm trying to *hook into the existing DE* or at least *provide my own EE*.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out its rather easy to write a Visual Studio 2010 Addin: Just download and install the Visual Studio 2010 SDK. Next, create an Addin project.

The `OnConnection` Method in the `Connect` class of your Addin will provide you with a `DTE2` instance. This can be used to poke around in the Visual Studio Debuggers Expression Evaluator:

```
DTE2 application; // fill this in OnConnection
application.Debugger.GetExpression("some c# code goes here")
```

The results are `Expression` instances, COM objects. Check the `Value` property.

**Homework:** Figure out how to wrap that up in a nice pythonic framework to make it seem seamless.

Comment: Anyone interested on how this is coming along: Just comment here, I'll gladly post the code to a project host in exchange for some help!

Comment: I've just asked about something similar here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749974/getting-debugger-context-in-f-interactive and then I found this question. I'm interested in how things are going with your implementation.

Comment: @Max, I lost interest ;) you can find the code at: http://code.google.com/p/ironpythondebugger/

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether this will help, but there's a good series about writing debuggers and extensions in managed code at:

http://devhawk.net/blog/2009/2/27/writing-an-ironpython-debugger-mdbg-101

> Before I start writing any debugger code, I thought it would help to
>   quickly review the .NET debugger infrastructure that is available as
>   well as the design of the MDbg command line debugger. Please note, my
>   understanding of this stuff is fairly rudimentary – Mike Stall is “da
>   man” if you’re looking for a .NET debugger blogger to read.
>
> The CLR provides a series of unmanaged APIs for things like hosting
>   the CLR, reading and writing CLR metadata and – more relevant to our
>   current discussion – debugging as well as reading and writing debugger
>   symbols. These APIs are exposed as COM objects. The CLR Debugging API
>   allows you to do those all the things you would expect to be able to
>   do in a debugger: attach to processes (actually, app domains), create
>   breakpoints, step thru code, etc. Of course, being an unmanaged API,
>   it’s pretty much unavailable to be used from IronPython. Luckily, MDbg
>   wraps this unmanaged API for us, making it available to any managed
>   language, including IronPython.
>
> The basic design of MDbg looks like this:
>
> image
>
> At the bottom is the “raw” assembly, which contains the C# definitions
>   of the unmanaged debugger API – basically anything that starts with
>   ICorDebug and ICorPublish. Raw also defines some of the metadata API,
>   since that’s how type information is exposed to the debugger.
>
> The next level up is the “corapi” assembly, which I refer to as the
>   low-level managed debugger API. This is a fairly thin layer that
>   translates the unmanaged paradigm into something more palatable to
>   managed code developers. For example, COM enumerators such as
>   ICorDebugAppDomainEnum are exposed as IEnumerable types. Also, the
>   managed callback interface gets exposed as .NET events. It’s not
>   perfect – the code is written in C# 1.0 style so there are no generics
>   or yields.
>
> Where corapi is the low-level API, “mdbgeng” is the high-level managed
>   debugger API. As you would expect, it wraps the low-level API and
>   provides automatic implementations of common operations. For example,
>   this layer maintains a list of breakpoints so you can create them
>   before the relevant assembly has been loaded. Then when assemblies are
>   loaded, it goes thru the list of unbound breakpoints to see if any can
>   be bound. It’s also this layer that automatically creates the main
>   entrypoint breakpoint.
>
> Finally, at the top we have the MDbg application itself, as well as
>   any MDbg extensions (represented by the … in the diagram above). The
>   mdbgext assembly defines the types shared between MDbg.exe and the
>   extension assemblies. MDbg has some cool extensions – including an
>   IronPython extension – but for now I’m focused on building something
>   as lightweight as possible, so I’m going to forgo an extensibility
>   mechanism, at least for now.
>
> My initial prototype was written against the high-level API. There
>   were two problems with this approach. The first is that there’s no
>   support for Just My Code in the high-level API. As I mentioned in my
>   last post, JMC support is critical for this project. Adding JMC
>   support isn’t hard, but I’m trying to make as few changes as possible
>   to the MDbg source, since I’m not interested in forking and
>   maintaining that code. Second, while the low-level API provides an
>   event-based API (OnModuleLoad, OnBreakpoint, OnStepComplete, etc), the
>   high-level API provides a more console-oriented looping API. I found
>   the event-driven API to be cleaner to work with and I’m thinking it
>   will work better if I ever build a GUI version of ipydbg. So I’ve
>   decided to work against the low-level API (aka corapi).
>
> I mentioned above that I didn’t want to change the MDbg source, but I
>   did make one small change. The separation of corapi and raw into two
>   separate assemblies is an outdated artifact of an earlier version of
>   MDbg. So I decided to combine these two into a single assembly called
>   CorDebug. Other than some simple cleanup to assembly level attributes
>   to make a single assembly possible, I haven’t changed the source code
>   at all.

Comment: Thanks. I had seen MDbg, but failed to compile the python extension). This seems a bit of a round-about root, since it is a standalone debugger and I'd like to just hook into the Visual Studio Debugger. Alas, I think I'm gonna lose this one :(