# Getting debugger context in F# interactive

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, f#, f#-interactive

Is it possible to somehow get the debugger context in F# interactive? For instance, if I hit a breakpoint in C# project then I would like to work with local variables in F# interactive, the same way I can work with them in immediate window. Is there any way to do so? Or do I need to create a debugger visualizer for that?

Answer (score 1):

Neither. You need to create an Expression Evaluator for it. Not sure if C# can be extended, but there is a sample in the VS SDK (the 2008 one at least).

Comment: Do you think it's not possible with debugger visualizer? I found this one on codeplex http://poshdebugvisualizer.codeplex.com and it seems to do what I want only with PowerShell. I would rather go with IronPython, IronRuby or even C#, if not with F#.

Comment: If you make it like that I guess, but not for functionality in the watch and immediate windows. From what I can see you need to decorate every type with that DebugVisualizer attribute, which is hardly convenient.

Comment: Here's another plugin http://code.google.com/p/linqpadvisualizer which allows to use visualizer with any C# type without any decoration.

Answer (score 0):

I've make very similar tool for Python, so I'm just using Python shell to evaluate some expressions like in Immediate Window. For this I've created a very simple VS Add-In and Python helper script. 
You can find sources on github - https://github.com/dp0h/VsImmediate